# Issue sending Http POST request to Nodejs Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I am having an issue sending over an array of information from my client.js to the node server using an http POST request. After a couple of days I think I have narrowed it down.

My current set up is the following:

Server

- After X amount of time, the server will start to ask clients to send their collected data.
- The server sends out only one request at a time, waiting to receive that clients info before sending a request to the next client

Client

- The client receives the request from the server
- Http stuff to send POST request is set up
- Array data is converted to json
- 1000ms is waited before sending the http post request

Server

- Post request is received & that data is added to a local array

My server.js

```
var http    = require('http')
  , connect = require('connect')
  , io      = require('socket.io')
  , fs      = require('fs')
  , uuid    = require('node-uuid')
  , _       = require('lodash');

// omitted event handers & pubnub setup

var app = connect().use(connect.static(__dirname)).use(connect.directory(__dirname));
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8888);
io = io.listen(server); 

// Following handles sending request to clients


function phaseTwo() {
  var count = 0;
  setTimeout(function() {

    pubnub.publish({
      channel: 'channel' + viewers[count],
      message: { message: 'measurements',
                 uuid:    'Server',
                 receiver: viewers[count] }
    });

    // set up server to listen for http POST
    app.use(function(req, res) {

     if (req.method == 'POST') {
       count++;
       req.on('data', function(chunk) {

         // add that array into one main array
         latencyData.push.apply(latencyData, chunk);

         dataCollected++;
       });

       pubnub.publish({
         channel: 'channel' + viewers[count],
         message: { message: 'measurements',
                    uuid:    'Server',
                    receiver: viewers[count] }
       });
     }
    }); // end app.use 
  }, msDuration);
}
```

client

```
  if (message.message == 'measurements') {
    console.log('   Received measurements event');

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'http://localhost:8888/';
    http.open('POST', url, true);

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", latency.length);
    // http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(latency);

    setTimeout( function() {
      http.send(myJsonString);
    }, 1000);

  }
```

The problem is that without that 1000ms delay on the client side, the server does not receive all the client's data. Even worse, when trying to scale up a few hundred clients, no more http posts are sent to the server after 240 clients have sent their info (there is enough ram for them)

With no delay on the client making the POST request, the server should be waiting for the current client to send over their information over before continuing. The other issue is that even with under the 240 clients, say testing 200 clients, even with no delay only about 10% of their data is received (this stuff is written to a text file at the end)

Im very new to using http post/get stuff so I think that is the issue. 
Is there anything immediately wrong from anyone experiences with http or nodejs stuff?

edit: I found one mistake. Back on the server side, on the post request whatever data is gotten from the server is added right away to the local array on the server without first making sure it's an array. Im not completely sure if this would break things enough to be the source of my problem

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using express and connect body parser?

Comment: The server I got right now was really just something I setup pretty quickly to display the static page of 2 html pages. Is there a possible issue with this?

Comment: There's no issue with doing this with core just making your own life harder by doing it.

Comment: that's true. I might try to optimize it after I get this working

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the code on the server-side: You're referencing variables like pubnub and latencyData that haven't been defined. You shouldn't have to let your clients wait 1000ms before responding, they should be able to respond immediately; It indicates a problem in program design. It is unclear when or where the phaseTwo function gets invoked.
Also I'd use strict equality operator **===**, because of type coercion: 1 == "1"; // true
*About your edit*: If you trust your clients, it shouldn't break.
My advice is to start over. Let me know if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

A POST can be pretty simply handled with Express.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser()); 

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('data retrieved');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: From what I understand this does make the set up simpler but can you tell me how this improves or what issue it is fixing from my current set up?

Answer (score 0):

Make proper route in server to handle incoming requests make your app aware of such routes.

You can `console.log(req)` to check it in server side how you are getting the request with all the data.